# In loaded event of user control, the other user control's control is null in WPF

Tags: wpf, user-controls, wpf-controls

I have user control, let say UC1.
Inside UC1, I have three more user controls, let say UC2, UC3 and UC4.

The issue is when I refer UC2's control from UC4 loaded event, the UC2's referred control is null.

Is it possible? Since the order of creation of User controls will be UC1, UC2, UC3 and UC4.

Technically when I am referring from loaded event of UC4, all the controls in UC2 should have been created. But in my case it is null.

Any ideas?

Comment: yeah... I've had a fair share of headaches with Loaded events in nested controls too. Not only they don't guarantee everything was loaded but their order can vary as well. In the past I ended up using IsVisibleChanged instead, not that it's a neat solution but for my purposes it worked

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be related to the instance because while checking if you have created another instance 
like this to check its content.

In UC4 :

```
UC2 obj_uc2 = new UC2();
```

Then it will give you null because its a new instance. For this you have to get the instance which is alive.